# Unique factorization into irreducible elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

> Given is $R$ an integral domain. With $P$ we will denote the subset of the irreducible elements of $R$, such that for every irreducible $x\in R$ exactly one element of $\left \{ ux\mid u\in R^{\times } \right \}$ lies in $P$. Show that $R$ is a UFD if and only if for every nonzero $c\in R$ there exists a unique unit $u\in R^{\times }$ and function $f:P\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ with $\left \{ p\in P\mid f(p)\neq 0 \right \}$ finite, such that $c=u\prod_{p\in P;f(p)\neq 0}p^{f(p)}$.

I am trying to prove this statement, but i don't really know how to do start in this case. All this looks like the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic, but it says that every integer is a product of prime numbers. In my case i have an arbitraty integral domain $R$ and i am not sure if it makes sense to try to prove the statement in case of $\mathbb{Z}$...

May i ask you for some help with this proof? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Proving it for $\mathbb{Z}$ is unlikely to help you, since proofs of FTA generally use the Euclidean domain property of $\mathbb{Z}$, which you are not guaranteed here.

Comment: The condition on $f$ doesn't look right. You probably want that $f(p)=0$ for all but finitely many $p$, not that $f(p)\neq 0$. If $f(p)\neq 0$ for all $p$ then you get that $c$ is divisible by every prime, which is nonsense since $c\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Every prime element of a commutative ring is irreducible. Therefore the implication $\Rightarrow$ is just the definition of a UFD.

To prove the implication $\Leftarrow$ ist suffices to show that every element of $P$ is prime. So assume $p\in P$ divides a product $ab$ of ring elements, and consider the factorizations of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: i don't think that $\implies$ is just the definition of UFD. You need to find the unique unit and the unique function such that the claim works. This does not come directly from the definition of UFD.